# Do coordination complexes with stronger ligands form more stable complexes?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, coordination-compounds

I read that chelate complexes generally are more stable than monodentate complexes. However, I noticed that in the case of $\ce{[Fe(CN)6]^3-}$ and $\ce{[Fe(en)3]^3+}$, this is not observed as the former is more stable. Why is this so?

Comment: See this post: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/43297/which-complexes-are-stable-ammine-complexes-or-carbonyl-complexes

Comment: @NilayGhosh Thanks, that helped. By the way, I have to ask: are you Nilay Ghosh from IIT Kharagpur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chelate complexes are more stable IF EVERYTHING ELSE IS THE SAME.

In your case, the anionic nature(cf. ethylenediamine is neutral) of cyanide makes cyanide a better sigma-donor than is ethylenediamine, while the pi-accepting nature(cf. ethylenediamine is pi-neutral, if not (hyperconjugative) pi-donating) of cyanide makes cyanide a better pi-acceptor than is ethylenediamine.